# Как передать индекс элемента в функцию?

Tags: javascript, массивы, html5

```js
button.forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener('click', openPopup);
});
```

в функцию openPopup нужно передать индекс нажатого item. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 5):

Индекс в перебираемой коллекции идет вторым аргументом у функции, которую Вы передаете в [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
collection.forEach(function(item, i) { 
   // one iteration
})
```

```js
function openPopup(event, index) {
    console.log(index, event);
}
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(button, index) {
    button.addEventListener('click',  e => openPopup(e, index));
});
```

```html
<button>нажми</button>
<button>на</button>
<button>кнопку</button>
<button>получишь</button>
<button>результат</button>
```

Comment: мне нужно передать index во внешнюю функцию

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, но почему button.onclick-то?

Comment: @vp_arth так меньше кода, вопрос же не про это, и этот слушатель тоже имеет право на использование, я его юзаю когда как раз нужна вытесняющая логика

Comment: @РустамГимранов, сделал минимально по ТЗ (сказано про передачу индекса, про передачу события - ни слова) и с минимальными правками ответа (автор ответа уже написал, почему `onclick` вместо  `addEventListener` у него, хоть я и не совсем согласен)

Comment: @br3t спасибо за участие, поменял на addEventListener, все таки так было у автора, ну и чтобы тапки не кидали тоже :)

Comment: Ну так теперь тапки за alert можно кидать)

Comment: @vp_arth а что, нативный popup